# What capabilities do you need to use AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault().AudioEndpointChanged in a universal application

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-phone-voip

In a Windows Phone 8 application you needed ID_CAP_VOIP to use

```
AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault().AudioEndpointChanged
```

What is the equivalent in a Universal Application? There don't appear to be any VOIP/Audio capabilities listed in the Capabilities tab on the Package.appxmanifest

(I'm starting to think this is impossible in an 8.1 Universal App)

Answer (score 1):

Old question but now I know the answer.

Two things which you need to do:
1. Tag the audio in question as "communications"

How to do this depends on what API you're using. It could be as simple as . Or you might have to call IAudioClient2::SetClientProperties with an AudioClientProperties structure whose AudioClientProperties.eCategory = AudioCategory_Communications.

2. Tag your app as either a "voice over IP" app or a "voicemail" app
   You should add file called WindowsPhoneReservedAppInfo.xml  to your project with the following contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <WindowsPhoneReservedAppInfo         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/phone/2013/windowsphonereservedappinfo">
     <SoftwareCapabilities>
       <SoftwareCapability Id="ID_CAP_VOIP" />
     </SoftwareCapabilities>
   </WindowsPhoneReservedAppInfo>
   ```

Look for more detailed explanation here:

[Playing audio to the earpiece from a Windows Phone 8.1 universal app](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2015/03/05/playing-audio-to-the-earpiece-from-a-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app.aspx)